# I'm Having Problem in pydroid 3 on my android device with espeak library

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, linux, pydroid

**code:**
*So This is my pydroid3 python script and when i try to run it*

```
import pyttsx3
speaker = pyttsx3.init()
speaker.say("Mama I Can Talk ")
speaker.runAndWait()
```

**error:**
*This is the error that occurs every time even though i downloaded all the espeak libraries (python_espeak) and all*

````
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/weakref.py", line 131, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 30, in __init__    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 50, in __init__    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/espeak.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import _espeak, toUtf8, fromUtf8
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/_espeak.py", line 18, in <module>
    dll = cdll.LoadLibrary('libespeak.so.1')
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 451, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen failed: library "libespeak.so.1" not found```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry pyttsx3 will not work on android. Install QPython and use the inbuilt modules in it. It neither support pyttsx3 but they use the phone's tts. So you can use that for tts