# How can I fix pyttsx3 initialization?

Tags: python, pyttsx3

Code:

```
import pyttsx3 
A=pyttsx3 init()
A.say('not working')
A.runAndWait()
```

Run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/1 ib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/_init__.py", line 20, in init
  eng = _active Engines [driver Name]
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/1ib/python3.9/weakref.py", line 137, in getitem_
  o = self.data[key]() KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
  start(fakepyfile, mainpyfile)
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
  exec(open(mainpyfile).read(), __main__.__dict__) File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/1ib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/_init__.py", line 22, in init
  eng Engine(driver Name, debug)
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/1 ib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 30, in _init_   
  self.proxy = driver. DriverProxy (weakref.proxy (self), driver Name, debug) 
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/1 ib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 50, in _init_
  self._module = importlib.import_module (name)
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/1 ib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name [level:], package, level) 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in gcd_import 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/1ib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/espeak.py", line 9, in <module>
  from import espeak, toUtf8, fromUtf8 
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/1 ib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/_espeak.py", line 18, in <module>
  dll = cdll. LoadLibrary('libespeak.so.1') 
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/1ib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 452, in LoadLibrary 
  return self._dlltype(name) 
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/1ib/python3.9/ctypes/_init__.py", line 374, in init 
  self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode) 
OSError: dlopen failed: library "libespeak.so.1" not found

[Program finished]
```

Comment: It's `pyttsx3.init()` in line 2...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65047288/im-having-problem-in-pydroid-3-on-my-android-device-with-espeak-library

Comment: Sorry my bad....in line 2 but that's my typing mistake here.....it's not working at all